# LINQ/Projection - Contains all wildcard for filtering

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, contains

Is there an equivalent "**" for Contains("*")?  I'm using some wildcards for filtering and if there isn't a filter applied then I need to return all?

```
string[] filter = {1,2};  // This is dynamic could be filtered values or {} empty.

// This works for filtering by products (1,2)
db.Products.Where(x => filter.Contains(x.ProdId));
```

What I really need to achieve is something like this:

```
// If the filter is empty get all results...if there is a filter passed the filter values in for select
db.Products.Where(x => x.ProdId.Contains(filter.Length == 0 ? "*" : filter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var result = db.Products.AsQueryable();

if(filter.Any())
    result = result.Where(x => filter.Contains(x.ProdId));
```

If the filter is not the only where condition, that's not a problem at all, you can define multiple `Where`s for your query:

```
var result = db.Products.Where(x => SomeCondition(x));

if(filter.Any())
    result = result.Where(x => filter.Contains(x.ProdId));
```

Comment: Thx for the reply.  I have multiple filters (5-6 of them) and would like to keep it on projected statement using ? : operator.

Comment: @JaJ: Please see the update that discusses multiple where statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can just add the where, if necessary:

```
var query = db.Products.AsQueryable();
if (filter.Any())
    query = query.Where(x => filter.Contains(x.ProdId));

// use query as needed
```

Comment: Reed, thanks for the reply! Adding on multiple where's worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

`db.Products.Where(x => !filter.Any() || filter.Contains(x.ProdId))`

Although I like the other answers listed :

`if(filter.Any()) 
    result = result.Where(x => filter.Contains(x.ProdId));`

In the first example, it will loop through the collection and determine that the filter does have items for every item in the result.  The second will only loop if there are items in the filter

Comment: This will not work. If filter is empty, `filter.Any` returns `false` and `filter.Contains(x.ProdId)` returns `false` as well.

Comment: if the filter is not empty and there is no match in the filter, then I would expect it to return no results

Comment: Correct. But if the filter is empty, he wants to have *all* objects returned. Your implementation however returns *none* in this case.

Comment: I guess that this is not going to work either, because the provider can't translate it to SQL. But I am not sure about that...

Comment: @SeattleLeonard: BANG fixed it!  Very cool!  Nice short circuit logic.  =)